# R: remove empty columns in a list within a list

Tags: r, list

How do I remove empty columns from a list within a list in R, when the columns are either "" or NA?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
x <- list( a = cars , b = ability.cov , d = mtcars )
x[[3]][2]<-""
```

So the second column in the third list is now all "", I wish to remove it from x

**EDIT**:The problem is I do not know which columns in which list (within the list) that is empty. I need some algorithm

I've tried the following which does not work for me:

```
 x<-x[,colSums(x!= "") != 0 ]
```

Comment: Could do `x2[[3]][2]<- NULL`

Comment: The problem is I do not know which columns in which list (within the list) that is empty. I need some algorithm.

Comment: @LAP: thank you for guiding me. May I ask, why is not the example data I provided appropriate?

Comment: @Erosennin Please disregard my former comment. But to further elaborate, the column you produce with `x[[3]][2]<-""` is not empty (as in `NULL`), but it is a `character` column with empty character strings.

Comment: In the first to elements you don't have columns, rather two vectors. How do you want to a handle those in case empty?

Comment: Partial solution: You can identify the list items that only contain empty `character` elements with `lapply(x, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) all(y == "")))`. This is not recursive though and won't work on deeper nested lists.

Comment: @LAP: thank you for pointing that out, you are indeed correct.

Comment: @David Arenburg: Then I would want to just remove them, thank you!

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. When would `a` and `b` considered as empty? There are no "columns" in `a` and `b` or you don't want to consider `a` and `b` at all because there are no "columns" in them. ?

Comment: Ok, I edited the example data so all are lists. @RonakShah: ok now?

Comment: @jogo: I have changed that in the question

Comment: @LAP: thank you for the code, but I am not completely sure how I take your code and remove the columns. I'm sorry, but I'm rather new to this.

Comment: @jogo: I'm so sorry, I fixed it now...

Comment: @jogo: wow thank you very much, that works like a charm! If you make an answer, I could accept this answer? Now I have to understand it, so I do not have to ask next time! Thank you very much, again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all columns with only value "" from the dataframes in the list you can do:

```
lapply(x, function(xi) xi[!sapply(xi, function(xii) all(xii==""))])
```

**explanation:**

- If you have a vector `xii` you can test it against "", this gives a vector of logical with length same as `xii`.
- `all(...)` is clear: the result is TRUE if all elements are TRUE
- `sapply(xi, ...)` is calculating this for each column of `xi`. It
  gives TRUE or FALSE for each column of `xi`
- `xi[!sapply()]` inverts the logical vector from `sapply()` and uses
  it as index for `xi`. If one element of the index is FALSE, the
  column is neglected in the result.
- `lapply(x, ...)` is running over your original list

*Do not forget to store the result in an object!* `xnew <- lapply(...)`

If you want to remove columns with only NA and "" as values:

```
lapply(x, function(xi) xi[!sapply(xi, function(xii) all(xii=="" | is.na(xii)))])
```

Comment: Wow, I am so grateful, thank you very much for the explanation!